# Expire index in mongoDB based on condition

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine, ttl

I have `boolean` field named `pending` in `Mongoengine` model in Python. I want the document to be removed after 1 hour only if `pending=True`. If I needed to remove the document after 1 hour unconditionally I would just set expire index. Is there some smart and easy way to add some conditional check to expire index?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid it is not directly possible to add some custom logic to the periodic cleaning of expired documents but as described in the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-ttl/#expiration-of-data) you could use a expire index and only set the indexed field from your application if `pending = True` - as documents without the field of the expire index are not removed this should work although not exactly what you requested.

Comment: In my case I will need to set the expire index initially (because pending=True at start). And when I set pending=False, I should remove the index. I am not sure how to achieve this with Mongoengine. There is no remove_index() function, and if I remove the entry from the _meta dictionary, it would remove for the whole collection, not just for the document. I have idea to set pending to Null instead of False, I guess indexes do not work on null. What do you suggest?

Comment: Well you could set null to the field which the expire index is based on whenever you change pending to False. If you need to restore the value at a later time when changing 'pending' back to True then you may need to introduce an additional field so that you have 2 date fields - one holding your date all the time and the other one holding the date only while pending = True. In this case the expire index would be based on the second field of course. Hope that makes sense :)

Comment: There is no case when pending will go back to true again, so I guess one index will be enough. Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 13):

Since MongoDB version 3.2 you can use Partial Indexes (in conjunction with TTL Indexes).

This index will remove all documents that had `pending = true` for 1 hour. If within this hour a document is updated and no longer pending, it will not be removed.

```
let keys = { lastModifiedDate: -1 };
let options = { 
    expireAfterSeconds: 3600, 
    partialFilterExpression: { pending: true }
};
db.getCollection("collection").createIndex(keys, options);
```

(Although this answer is probably no longer relevant to you, I'm sure someone else will find it useful in the future)